# How to install KDE icon theme package in Arch Linux?

Tags: awesome, digikam

digiKam 5 no longer comes bundled with an icon theme, so when running in Awesome WM there are no icons at all. In Configure digiKam → Miscellaneous → Icon theme it simply says "Use Icon Theme From System".

Are there any **icon theme packages which can be used with digiKam?** Preferably without installing a whole chunk of KDE or AUR packages. There doesn't seem to be any in the optional digiKam deps:

```
$ pacman --query --info digikam | grep 'Optional Deps'
Optional Deps   : kipi-plugins: more tools and plugins
```

Searching the package repository for KDE icons or themes didn't yield anything obviously usable.

Answer (score 1):

Look at:
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/qt

(Configuration of Qt5 apps under environments other than KDE)

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific? URL-only answers are discouraged on this site.